# how to display country/region/subject/post reasonably

Tags: links

Using USA, Canada, and Australia for example, I'd like a main page showing the three countries.  The next page would be states, or provinces, along with a default of nationwide.  The next page would be subject, budget, legislative, executive as well as nation specific subject areas.  Finally a page listing all posts.

For example USA>nationwide>ledislative issues>posts should be different than USA>New York>ledislative issues>posts.

How do I produce this type of site?

Comment: This question is not about WordPress, so it shouldn't be posted in this forum. When you have a specific WordPress question feel free to post it here. You will have more success with getting an answer when you are really specific about what you have tried so far (with code examples) and which problems you have encountered.

Comment: Well, I see it as WordPress related, and I am at a loss for where to start.  I've searched a number of sites, but have see nothing similar, where I can extract from some one else info.

Comment: People would have an easier time answering your question if you were way more specific about your setup, your theme, your code, what problem you are trying to solve, which snags you have encountered along the way. From what you are describing here I believe you could easily set up a site with WordPress that does this. Just use nested pages or categories and enter the desired information on each page.